# Moving textarea content to input field and back removes new lines. How to overcome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

That's it.
The web app that I am working on is pretty big and I am not sure whether field can get their types changed.

Anyway,
we have a textarea in a popup that on some text entered and Save button in the popup clicked, moves all the textbox content to an input field of type text.
Later if a user clicks on the input field he gets the popup with the textbox rendered again and the textbox content is obtained from the input.
The issue occurs already at the first shift as all new lines are removed on moving the text from the textarea to the input field.

I have found that the reason for new lines missing is that html requires 
 tags introduced in order to render those, but I have expected the text to keep formatting after getting back to the same textbox.
Why are new-line characters removed from the string?

Do you have any suggestion how to overcome that? I am not sure whether I will be able to change the field types.

Comment: input elements cannot have line breaks, hence the reason they are removed when you take the text from the textarea and copy it in. You will need to replace line breaks with a character that can be displayed in the textbox, then put the line breaks back when moving to the textarea again.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any suggestions for that character? I see input will remove standard new line and <br> will be rendered in the exact way, I am not sure what character should do the job?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan , do you have any suggestions regarding this? I am not sure which character to substitute new line with,that can be rendered as something acceptable in the input box.
I have tried <br>, &#13;&#10; but it all doesn't get rendered as a special character in the input box. 
I can't use a random character as it is going to display incorrect content in the input box.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something you could do is, when you save and move the content to the input, you can store the "textarea" value on a javascript variable. Then, when opening the popup again, place the variable value to the textarea, and the formatting will be still there.

Comment: That is an idea that occurred to me too. But I have multitude of those inputs and they all use the same textarea for previewing.
It would mean I would have to work with a number of varibles, not known in advance.

Comment: How are you treating the input's? With id's? If that's the case, create an array, instead of a variable. Then use the div id as the array index.

Comment: Yes, that could really be a solution. Thanks